# graphviz: left/right align nodes instead of centering?

Tags: graphviz

Is there any way to get graphviz to left-align or right-align nodes in the same rank, instead of centering?

[image]

```
   digraph h {
     rankdir=LR;

     node [shape=record,height=.08,fontsize=11];

     elk[label="elk|I am an American Elk"];

     buffalo[label="buffalo|Just a buffalo|everywhere I go|people know the part I'm playing"];

     cow[label="cow|moo"];

     moose[label="Bullwinkle J. Moose|Hey Rocky, watch me pull a rabbit out of my hat!"];

     zoo [label="zoo|<p0>|<p1>|<p2>|<p3>"];

     zoo:p0 -> elk;
     zoo:p1 -> cow;
     zoo:p2 -> moose;
     zoo:p3 -> buffalo;
   }
```

Answer (score 28):

It's nice to see someone working with such weighty data.

Here's one kludgey and unsatisfying way:

```
digraph h {
     rankdir=LR;
     node [shape=record,height=.08,fontsize=11];
     zoo [label="zoo|<p0>|<p1>|<p2>|<p3>"];

     node [width=3.5];
     elk[label="elk\l|I am an American Elk\l",];
     buffalo[label="buffalo\l|Just a buffalo\l|everywhere I go\l|people know the part I'm playing\l"];
     cow[label="cow\l|moo\l"];
     moose[label="Bullwinkle J. Moose\l|Hey Rocky, watch me pull a rabbit out of my hat!\l"];

     zoo:p0->elk; zoo:p1 -> cow; zoo:p2 -> moose; zoo:p3 -> buffalo;
}
```

Give each box in that rank the same (empirically determined) width, then left-align the text using the weird `\l` "left-aligned linebreak".

Comment: Hmm. I don't need the *text* left-aligned in the node (centering is fine), I just want the nodes left-aligned, & don't like constant width.

Comment: The reason is because a node position in a graph is in all situation calculated by it's center. The dimension of it's labels are also dependend on non-graph attributes like font-with and/or font-family. Nothing what a direct graph calculation is aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: [Top-align nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935039/top-align-nodes/75734893#75734893)

Adding `node[rankjustify=min]` before "zoo" and following the instructions pointed to above will give:
[image]