# Make graphviz nodes left align

Tags: alignment, graphviz, dot

I want the nodes in the second column (C and E) to left align, rather than center.

```
digraph left {
    graph [rankdir="LR", splines=ortho];
    node [shape=record];

    l1 [label="A\l|B\l"];
    l2 [label="C\l|short\l"];
    l3 [label="E\l|long long text\l"];

    l1 -> l2;
    l1 -> l3;
}
```

[image]

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110914/graphviz-left-right-align-nodes-instead-of-centering).

But the suggested method of using constant width for nodes is not suitable for me. I want to have them different widths depending on corresponding label widths.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the node position in a graph is in all situations calculated from it's center. Until there is no other implementation, the only way to achieve an "aligned" look-a-like is to use a fitting width.

```
digraph left {
    graph [rankdir=LR splines=ortho]
    node [shape=record]

    l1 [label="A\l|B\l"]
    l2 [label="C\l|short\l" width=1.3]
    l3 [label="E\l|long long text\l"]

    l1 -> l2
    l1 -> l3
}
```

results in this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: [Top-align nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935039/top-align-nodes/75734893#75734893)

Adding `node[rankjustify=min]` before "l1" and following the instructions pointed to above will give:
[image]