# Graphviz: align nodes on left side instead of centering (With answer)

Tags: nodes, graphviz, rank

I made a python script to plot a directory structure using graphviz.
In order to render the graph correctly, I use rankdir=LR. However, nodes having the same rank are centered.

See the following image.

[image: Graph result]

As you can see, nodes like ".gitignore", ".travis.yml", etc don't have the same width because of their label.
I would like to have nodes in the same rank aligned on the left side no matter their width.

I have seen other related posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110914/graphviz-left-right-align-nodes-instead-of-centering/2112178) but I don't want to force nodes width.

Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your answers and have a nice day.

P.S.:
Here's a sample of my graph code:

```
strict digraph projetcStructure { 
    graph [overlap=false, splines=ortho, ranksep=0.05]
    edge[arrowhead=none, color=black]
    node[fontname="DejaVu Sans Mono", fontsize=14]
    "e0ec0f89f0745e25b725768b304be71e" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/file-directory.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>TechnicalReport</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=2]
    "77a7da2a6f864418dd23f49f9c5e9804" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/git-merge.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>.gitignore</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "373d5e485b88f76e79d5bab15a88759e" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "8e58ce33bdaaa1db79bab7080019c6fe" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/travis.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>.travis.yml</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "b56aa426f8ad0d8a7704c909f2473b70" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "98a5f187b3527ca7f00643e7907b3453" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/book.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>LICENSE</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "07adcea039d69fb282b22eebd8daf537" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "ede2c50901cc59eeb8987d630d055b22" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/terminal.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>makeScript.sh</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "8f182d8be99f90432a2bec25a864bf19" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "53ccb88dccecc95c401d180aa34ac0ac" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/note.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>README.rst</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "f6ffc62db5cefc5b4a1eb2e6a3731802" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "3f917d2353bb6c1c156b18a78f23cf71" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/file.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>requirements.txt</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "acc1004c581f3b603d2a33092ffcfe61" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "2d05acf91c352a7ac491e18dcf65fc9c" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/settings.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>setup.cfg</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "8e1760a00144fca5272f341da0873674" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "b78eb5bb77cb04f62506859fb1ab76f8" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/terminal.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>test.sh</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "cc60f62b1b3d0cf8c266074b7139b567" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "3512568f6984d40e6353aa13b5029dc3" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/mark-github.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>.github</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "88ae0eb0f89e79ddff8e2b1fe470a488" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "9b43ae74e93bdb3dadace6084e333a27" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/file-directory.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>foldertree</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "2f9f172522c65ab785d2c23db909b36a" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "e7925cdfdefd09112b8b3c8b5ddde087" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/file-directory.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>generated</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "0b54fbb48c26181df9c8a5fd3bab1049" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "69d5f4cf4e091e008cb1f4de43692b4d" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/file-directory.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>TechnicalReportGenerator</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "c4f859f4d369226348a4eb08adab0afc" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "0ab55395ce4ef62f7a9f5f72201ce0ae" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/file-directory.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>worklog</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "9b4f2a57b302961cd3509dd307121cfa" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "77a7da2a6f864418dd23f49f9c5e9804" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/git-merge.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>.gitignore</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "8e58ce33bdaaa1db79bab7080019c6fe" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/travis.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>.travis.yml</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "98a5f187b3527ca7f00643e7907b3453" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/book.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>LICENSE</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "ede2c50901cc59eeb8987d630d055b22" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/terminal.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>makeScript.sh</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "53ccb88dccecc95c401d180aa34ac0ac" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/note.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>README.rst</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "3f917d2353bb6c1c156b18a78f23cf71" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/file.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>requirements.txt</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "2d05acf91c352a7ac491e18dcf65fc9c" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/settings.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>setup.cfg</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "b78eb5bb77cb04f62506859fb1ab76f8" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/terminal.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>test.sh</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "3512568f6984d40e6353aa13b5029dc3" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/mark-github.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>.github</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "9b43ae74e93bdb3dadace6084e333a27" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/file-directory.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>foldertree</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "e7925cdfdefd09112b8b3c8b5ddde087" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/file-directory.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>generated</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "69d5f4cf4e091e008cb1f4de43692b4d" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/file-directory.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>TechnicalReportGenerator</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    "0ab55395ce4ef62f7a9f5f72201ce0ae" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, width=3.7555555555555555, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/foldertree/octicons/file-directory.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>worklog</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=1]
    {rank=same;  "373d5e485b88f76e79d5bab15a88759e" "b56aa426f8ad0d8a7704c909f2473b70" "07adcea039d69fb282b22eebd8daf537" "8f182d8be99f90432a2bec25a864bf19" "f6ffc62db5cefc5b4a1eb2e6a3731802" "acc1004c581f3b603d2a33092ffcfe61" "8e1760a00144fca5272f341da0873674" "cc60f62b1b3d0cf8c266074b7139b567" "88ae0eb0f89e79ddff8e2b1fe470a488" "2f9f172522c65ab785d2c23db909b36a" "0b54fbb48c26181df9c8a5fd3bab1049" "c4f859f4d369226348a4eb08adab0afc" "9b4f2a57b302961cd3509dd307121cfa"}
"e0ec0f89f0745e25b725768b304be71e" -> "373d5e485b88f76e79d5bab15a88759e"
"373d5e485b88f76e79d5bab15a88759e" -> "b56aa426f8ad0d8a7704c909f2473b70"
"b56aa426f8ad0d8a7704c909f2473b70" -> "07adcea039d69fb282b22eebd8daf537"
"07adcea039d69fb282b22eebd8daf537" -> "8f182d8be99f90432a2bec25a864bf19"
"8f182d8be99f90432a2bec25a864bf19" -> "f6ffc62db5cefc5b4a1eb2e6a3731802"
"f6ffc62db5cefc5b4a1eb2e6a3731802" -> "acc1004c581f3b603d2a33092ffcfe61"
"acc1004c581f3b603d2a33092ffcfe61" -> "8e1760a00144fca5272f341da0873674"
"8e1760a00144fca5272f341da0873674" -> "cc60f62b1b3d0cf8c266074b7139b567"
"cc60f62b1b3d0cf8c266074b7139b567" -> "88ae0eb0f89e79ddff8e2b1fe470a488"
"88ae0eb0f89e79ddff8e2b1fe470a488" -> "2f9f172522c65ab785d2c23db909b36a"
"2f9f172522c65ab785d2c23db909b36a" -> "0b54fbb48c26181df9c8a5fd3bab1049"
"0b54fbb48c26181df9c8a5fd3bab1049" -> "c4f859f4d369226348a4eb08adab0afc"
"c4f859f4d369226348a4eb08adab0afc" -> "9b4f2a57b302961cd3509dd307121cfa"
    {rank=same;  "77a7da2a6f864418dd23f49f9c5e9804" "8e58ce33bdaaa1db79bab7080019c6fe" "98a5f187b3527ca7f00643e7907b3453" "ede2c50901cc59eeb8987d630d055b22" "53ccb88dccecc95c401d180aa34ac0ac" "3f917d2353bb6c1c156b18a78f23cf71" "2d05acf91c352a7ac491e18dcf65fc9c" "b78eb5bb77cb04f62506859fb1ab76f8" "3512568f6984d40e6353aa13b5029dc3" "9b43ae74e93bdb3dadace6084e333a27" "e7925cdfdefd09112b8b3c8b5ddde087" "69d5f4cf4e091e008cb1f4de43692b4d" "0ab55395ce4ef62f7a9f5f72201ce0ae"}
"373d5e485b88f76e79d5bab15a88759e" -> "77a7da2a6f864418dd23f49f9c5e9804"
"b56aa426f8ad0d8a7704c909f2473b70" -> "8e58ce33bdaaa1db79bab7080019c6fe"
"07adcea039d69fb282b22eebd8daf537" -> "98a5f187b3527ca7f00643e7907b3453"
"8f182d8be99f90432a2bec25a864bf19" -> "ede2c50901cc59eeb8987d630d055b22"
"f6ffc62db5cefc5b4a1eb2e6a3731802" -> "53ccb88dccecc95c401d180aa34ac0ac"
"acc1004c581f3b603d2a33092ffcfe61" -> "3f917d2353bb6c1c156b18a78f23cf71"
"8e1760a00144fca5272f341da0873674" -> "2d05acf91c352a7ac491e18dcf65fc9c"
"cc60f62b1b3d0cf8c266074b7139b567" -> "b78eb5bb77cb04f62506859fb1ab76f8"
"88ae0eb0f89e79ddff8e2b1fe470a488" -> "3512568f6984d40e6353aa13b5029dc3"
"2f9f172522c65ab785d2c23db909b36a" -> "9b43ae74e93bdb3dadace6084e333a27"
"0b54fbb48c26181df9c8a5fd3bab1049" -> "e7925cdfdefd09112b8b3c8b5ddde087"
"c4f859f4d369226348a4eb08adab0afc" -> "69d5f4cf4e091e008cb1f4de43692b4d"
"9b4f2a57b302961cd3509dd307121cfa" -> "0ab55395ce4ef62f7a9f5f72201ce0ae"

}
```

### [EDIT]

After a few researches and thanks to @TomServo, I have been able to "fix" the nodes width.

I use the following code. ImageFont doc can be found [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFont.html)

```py
font = ImageFont.truetype('DejaVuSansMono.ttf', FONT_SIZE)
width = font.getsize("YOUR STRING TO MEASURE HERE")[0]
# convert pixels to inches and add extra space for icons and margins
# icon size is defined as points which is a 72's of an inch
width = width / GRAPHVIZ_DPI + ((1 / 72) * 20 * 2)
```

Then the result:

[image: Better graph]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't think there is a way to achieve the effect you want without fixing the width of the nodes in a rank.  You may want to reconsider though because making your nodes the same width really makes the graph much neater:

```
strict digraph projetcStructure { 
    graph [overlap=false, splines=ortho, ranksep=0.05, rankdir=LR]
    edge[arrowhead=none, color=black]
    "2f173bfac231270e0418210e8a3552d2" [shape=folder, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/FolderTree/octicons/file-directory.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>TechnicalReport</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=3, width=2.0]
    "6b9ec0d7104a108a26ba34f9672f35a5" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/FolderTree/octicons/git-merge.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>.gitignore</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=2, width=2.0]
    "6a20aaea09ab2aac28e4b8f50f46d9e6" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "ad9d05da3ebed612a90ab85a30d039d7" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/FolderTree/octicons/travis.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>.travis.yml</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=2, width=2.0]
    "2bef36c3d9fd70fec1b1d395ec891948" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "023bdc0f2f34c3d14a028c1190295079" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/FolderTree/octicons/book.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>LICENSE</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=2, width=2.0]
    "1a7aeec41293922786ed460f863c197c" [shape="point", width=0, height=0]
    "418903823b3792736b96279643175a80" [shape=note, style=filled, colorscheme=ylgnbu3, label=<<TABLE><TR><TD WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="20" FIXEDSIZE="TRUE"><IMG SRC="/mnt/e/Documents/3eme/TechnicalReport/FolderTree/octicons/terminal.png" SCALE="TRUE"/></TD><TD>makeScript.sh</TD></TR></TABLE>>, color=2, width=2.0]
```

Notice the `width=2.0` at the end of the first few nodes.  This makes them the same width and cleans up the ragged look a little.

Also, do put `rankdir=LR` near the top as shown, and as you mentioned in your question.

[image]

To "precompute" the width necessary, on a Windows system I would use the Graphics namespace to determine width, something like this:

```
private void MeasureStringWidth(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // Set up string.
    string measureString = "Measure String";
    Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);

    // Set maximum width of string.
    int stringWidth = 200;

    // Measure string.
    SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
    stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont, stringWidth);

    // Draw rectangle representing size of string.
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), 0.0F, 0.0F, stringSize.Width, stringSize.Height);

    // Draw string to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(measureString, stringFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
}
```

Then convert the `stringSize.Width` value to inches for example.  Add a little padding, add a little extra for your included icon graphics and then use that for your uniform width.

Finally, if you're not on a Windows system, or not using .NET, there may be other ways to [measure the width of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193798/how-can-i-measure-the-width-of-a-string-rendering-via-tkfont-without-creating-a), as in the  example with python and tkinter.  So don't give up, you can do it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will fix the node width. Do you know if there is a way to ”precompute” the width of the bigger node in order to apply it to each node?

Comment: The Graphviz reference manual gives no clue as to figuring out the largest width, so I don't think it supports it.  However, see my edited answer for an additional idea that will work with a little effort.

Comment: I haven’t seen anything in the manual either, this is why I asked. I will try your way and estimate the width based on the number of char in the name of the longest file and font size. I am using Python so I don’t think this will be an issue. I had already thought doing it that way but I wanted to know if there were easier ways of doing it. Thank you very much for your answer. Have a nice week end.

Comment: I have been able to find a way to calculate the width. Thank you very much.